# add_lvalue_reference/add_rvalue_reference and cv-qualified type

Tags: c++, std

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) about `std::add_lvalue_reference`/`std::add_rvalue_reference`:

> If T is an object type or a function type that **has no cv- or ref- qualifier**, provides a member typedef type which is T&&, **otherwise type is T**.

Does it mean that if T is *const* or *volatile* than T is not converted to reference? If no, then what does it mean *"has no cv-qualifier"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to say that the result is respectively `T&` or `T&&` if either:

- `T` is an object type, or
- `T` is a function type that does not have any cv-qualifiers and does not have a ref-qualifier.

The restriction "has no cv- or ref-qualifier" does not apply to object types. It applies to function types because if a function type has a cv- or ref-qualifier, then it is not possible to create the referenced type. See [Abominable Function Types](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) for some discussion.

Answer (score 5):

> Does it mean that if T is const or volatile than T is not converted to reference?

Yes, but only if it is a function.

The quote from cppreference can be a little confusing.  cppreference has

> If T is an object type or a function type that has no cv- or ref- qualifier, provides a member typedef type which is T&&, otherwise type is T.

which can make you believe the cv-qualifer part applies to both objects and functions, but this is not the case.  The actual [text from the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.referenceable) is

> an object type, a function type that does not have cv-qualifiers or a ref-qualifier, or a reference type

so any object type and any function without a *cv-qualifier* and *ref-qualifier* will yield a reference.  references or functions with a *cv-qualifier* and/or *ref-qualifier* will yield `T`

---

When you see *cv-qualifier* that means const and or volatile qualifier, i.e. it is a const and or volatile object or const or volatile qualified function.  *ref-qualifier* that means reference qualifier, i.e. the function can only be called on an lvalue or rvalue: `void foo() &` or `void foo() &&`.

Comment: But _gcc_ and _clang_ actually convert to reference even cv-types: [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e65962e74a79de9). And it makes sense.

Comment: @anton_rh The statement is meant as _"(if `T` is an object type) or (if `T` is a function type that has no cv- or ref-qualifiers) ..."_. It seems you are reading it as _"If `T` is an object type [...] that has no cv- or ref-qualifier ..."_, which is not what is meant there.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: good point. This reading order is also specified by the C++ precedence rules :-)